# How to show first five images from database in datalist

Tags: asp.net

I want to show first five images from database in datalist and after some time like 2 or 4 second, shows next five Images. would suggest.

Comment: What you have done? Share please. If you can show images in datalist and just want to repeat the process. You can use javascript timer

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to do jquery ajax. You can use "Add Rotater" control.
here is an [exapmple](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=202)